# Query Result: What is $row[0]

Tags: php

I know this may sound like a stupid question from a programming-newbie, but I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

After a query, what does `$row[0]` stand for/ result in?

Is my understanding correct that `$row[0]` shows ALL results?

HERE ARE EXAMPLES:

```
$query = "SELECT count(commentid) from comments where jokeid = $jokeid";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row[0] == 0)

{

   echo "No comments posted yet.&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";



} else

{

   echo $row[0] . "\n";
   echo "&nbsp;comments posted.&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
```

AND THIS ONE

```
$query = "Select count(prodid) from products where catid = $catid";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      if ($row[0] == 0)
      {
         echo "<h2><br>Sorry, there are no products in this category</h2>\n";
      }
      else
      {
         $totrecords = $row[0];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the value of the first column of your query (in this case, `count(...)`).

Answer (score 4):

`$row[0]` will simply echo the first column in your database.

0 is the first because all arrays in PHP (and in most programming languages) are zero-based - they simply start with zero.

Answer (score 2):

$row[0] will be the value of the first column in your results. If you use [mysql_fetch_assoc($result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)) you will have an array in the form:

```
array(column_name => column_value);
```

e.g.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_asssoc($result);
$value_column_1 = $row['column_1'];
```

You can also use [mysql_fetch_object($result)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) to get an object with column names as the parameters.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$value = $row->column_name
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array()` takes the next (in your examples first) row out of the resultset and stores the data in an array `$row`.

`$row[0]` now represents the first value of that row.

So in total in your examples the variable holds the first value of the first row of your resultset.